# How to add spacing between all fixed widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5) based GUI application. I just want all the widgets like *Textbox* or *Buttons* to have a fixed size. And i successfully did that! **But**

I want that if someone resizes the window, the widgets must have their same fixed size **BUT** it should increase/decrease the spaces between them, rather than changing the size of widgets. (I don't want my widgets to be resized, that's why i opt this method to increase/decrease their spaces between each other).

For example :
[image: Original Application state]
(Original application state)
[image: vertically resized]
(Trying to resize the window to bigger size vertically, but you can see that no buttons widget's size changed. Just more space was added...) 
[image: horizontal resize]
(Trying to resize horizontally)

I found that `QSizePolicy` does the same thing that i want, but didn't get any good examples anywhere.

**This is my code :**

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor, QPolygon
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint, QRectF
import sys

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("test app")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.label.setText("my first label!")
        self.label.move(110,10)
        self.label.resize(180,25)

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("Fixed Button size!")
        self.b1.move(180,250)
        self.b1.resize(110, 25)
        self.b1.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Arial
        """)

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):

        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 50, 8))
        qp.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 299)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(250, 255, 250))
        qp.drawRect(110, 50, 180, 180)


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

It hides the widgets when resized. I want to make the buttons and text widgets to add spaces between them, when resized. Now it's hiding those widgets because i didn't used `hstack` or `vstack`. I know.

Just don't know how to use `QSizePolicy` for the spacing purpose.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Sorry. Now is it better explained? @eyllanesc

Comment: My bad. Now i have provided my code. @eyllanesc

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand your question, you could put an image that shows what you get now and another image with what you want to get.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi your code doesn't reflect what is shown in the images. Which one are you actually going to use?

Comment: Sorry for my misleading code. Now you can check it back again. It's exactly according to the image shown above. @eyllanesc

Comment: From what I understand, you want to get the second image, am I correct? And what do you want to get when the window is resized horizontally?

Comment: Yes you are correct! I want the second image when resized vertically. But when you resize it horizontally, it should look like the 3rd image i recently uploaded. You can compare it with the original images, about how it differs from vertically and horizontally resized application. @eyllanesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to obtain there are multiple solutions, my solution uses the properties of the layouts:

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("test app")

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label.setFixedWidth(100)
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 50, 8)")

        lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        lineedit.setFixedWidth(180)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Fixed Button size!")
        button.setFixedSize(110, 25)
        button.setStyleSheet(
            """
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Arial
        """
        )

        widget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        widget.setFixedSize(180, 180)
        widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(250, 255, 250)")

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        right_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        botton_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        botton_widget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        botton_widget.setFixedWidth(180)
        hlay2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(botton_widget)
        hlay2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hlay2.addStretch()
        hlay2.addWidget(button)

        glay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(right_container)
        glay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(), 0, 0, 5, 1)
        glay.addWidget(lineedit, 0, 1)
        glay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(), 1, 1)
        glay.addWidget(widget, 2, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        glay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(), 3, 1)
        glay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(), 0, 2, 5, 1)
        glay.addWidget(botton_widget, 4, 1)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hlay.addWidget(label)
        hlay.addWidget(right_container)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! @eyllanesc for your help. That's what i needed. But i can't understand some few things. I mean i didn't get your code after line 37, i.e from `central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()`. Can you make me understand what it does and how this whole concept worked out after that line?